# Windows Vista Corrupt Registry

Tags: windows-vista, boot, windows-registry

I have a laptop with Windows Vista Basic. It won't boot. I have tried an automatic repair with the installation disc but the error cannot be repaired automatically. According to the test results the registry is corrupt.

I have found this guide on how to recover from a corrupt registry with Windows XP
[here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307545). Is this guide also applicable to Vista or is there an alternative method I can try (short of reinstalling Vista)?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 0):

Use the Vista DVD, boot from it and do a system restore, pick a date before the corruption.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial142.html

.

As far as the XP method, I have never tried it on Vista or W7, I assume it would work, but cannot say for sure, trying it will be at your own risk.

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't any system restore points.